# PHP file for "Web Service" queries between IOS App and Database

Tags: php, ios, mysql

I am developing an IOS application that communicates with a database with "web service" requests.
To do this, I write the many SQL queries in a single PHP file that serves as a "bridge" between the application and the database.
My question is the following :
Do I have to make several PHP files (which grouped feature-ordered templates) or can I write all PHP queries in one file (which is so large)?
In addition, some queries allow me to upload images to the server with a rather long transfer time. If I keep these queries in the same PHP file, will it "block" or "slow down" access to this file for other users? Should I make PHP files apart for upload?

For the moment, I develop this application locally and I do not see any problem with a single PHP file. But I have a doubt when putting into production on a real server.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make serveral page for each web service or you can do it only in one page. But it dependes upon your application requirements. If it is a huge application then, it would be better to use different webservice for every api call.
The main demerit of single page web service is, if there is a problem in your 1 function then the application will not work at all and you might be think where is the issue.

If you used different web service for different functionality then it will not work on that page only and it will not affect other pages of your application.

Comment: OK,
I also wanted to know if the upload of large images can block access to this unique file (in case the PHP code for the upload is still in this file) for other users?

Comment: No, it will not affect to any other users. If your code is bug free.

Comment: I have not enough reputation for that ;-(